# Creating a simple GridLayout not working

Tags: java, android, android-gridlayout

I'm trying to create a simple grid layout in android programatically.  It will have a certain number of rows and columns, and just color each square differently.  What I have tried seems to color every square the value of the last view (I believe), but I'm not quite sure why.  The `GridLayout` doesn't seem to have very clear documentation.  Here's my code:

```
public static final int GAME_BOARD_COLUMNS = 8;
public static final int GAME_BOARD_ROWS = 8;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game_board, container, false);
    createGameBoard(view);

    return view;
}

private void createGameBoard(View view) {
    GridLayout grid = (GridLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.grid_layout_game_board);
    grid.setRowCount(GAME_BOARD_ROWS);
    grid.setColumnCount(GAME_BOARD_COLUMNS);

    for (int i = 0; i < GAME_BOARD_ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < GAME_BOARD_COLUMNS; j++) {
            GridLayout.LayoutParams params = 
                new GridLayout.LayoutParams(GridLayout.spec(i), GridLayout.spec(j));

            View square = new View(getActivity());
            int color = Color.rgb(
                    (int) ((255.0f / (float) GAME_BOARD_ROWS) * i),
                    (int) ((255.0f / (float) GAME_BOARD_COLUMNS) * j),
                    100);
            square.setBackgroundColor(color);

            grid.addView(square, params);
        }
    }
}
```

and the gameboard layout is very simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid_layout_game_board"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</GridLayout>
```

When I run this, my screen is simply blue, can't quite figure out why, while debugging the color is different every iteration, so I'm guessing it's not really adding the views to the `GridLayout` correctly.  Anybody had any experience in how to properly populate a `GridLayout` programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not need to specify *LayoutParams*. The *GridLayout* should add cells sequentially as you provide them (using *grid.addView(...)*).

Another possible issue is that your *square* View object. You should make sure that the View object returned has a width and height set and that none of the children in the view (if any) have any widths or heights specified that might fill your screen.

Comment: Actually specifying a width and height for the view did (sort of) fix the problem, as I guess they default to match parent, which is the entire grid layout (not their cell).

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia you needed gravity

Comment: Could this be explained further? I'm having the same problem; setting some width/height for the view "fixes" it, but I want all the cells to be the same size filling the whole gridlayout together. I *could* "fix" this by getting the screen dimensions and calculating the sizes of the cells myself. But this obviously isn't what I want to do and IMO it seems like this is exactly the job GridLayout should do. @Elltz I tried with gravity but it didn't seem to work (this is on api<21 btw so no weights). I might be doing it wrong though?

Comment: @Alowaniak have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718928/android-gridlayout-api-21/27719757#27719757) ? let me know if it does help you