# Android - How do I move my button programmatically in a grid layout?

Tags: android, user-interface, button

I'm making an android app where if you click on a `Button`, it will create a `Textview`. But my problem is that when the `TextView` is placed inside the `GridLayout`, the `Button` stays where it is. I want to move the button relative to where the `TextView` is placed.

Answer (score 0):

Your `TextView` in the `GridLayout` is controlled by the `GridLayout`, `GridLayout` works in a different way as compared to other `ViewGroup`s-afaik, [an ex of gridlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718928/android-gridlayout-api-21/27719757#27719757) you will see that it uses `column` and `row`, so if you want to achieve what you want to achieve alter its column to the prefered place.

to be safe use a different `Viewgroup`