# Issues trying to create GridLayout with elements of different size

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-gridlayout

I'm trying to create a static grid-like layout in Android so I'm using `GridLayout` instead of `GridView`.

This is the layout I'm trying to achieve
[image]

Using the code from [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_the_Android_GridLayout_in_XML_Layout_Resources) as a base. I'm also a little confused about specifying `layout_{weight, margin}` on every element inside the grid, since it's my understanding that the `rowSpan` and `colSpan` parameters should take care of that. Is this not incorrect?

Any pointers?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="2"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1">
        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:text="Button" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/card_view1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1">
        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/card_view3"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_row="1">
        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:text="Button" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718928/android-gridlayout-api-21/27719757#27719757)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were so close, try this instead:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="2"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2">
        <Button
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:text="Button" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1">
        <Button
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view3"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1">
        <Button
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:text="Button" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</GridLayout>
```

You need to use `layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"` for the first item, to stretch the whole row. And play with `layout_columnWeight` for the 2nd and 3rd item.

Comment: Not exactly what I specified, there seems to be an issue with the rowSpan of the first elements, it's ignored [here](http://i.imgur.com/kQ7YJqs.png)

Comment: Can you clarify more? The first element takes 2 columns, isn't that what you want?

Comment: Sorry, I got mixed up! This is completely correct, thank you!